# TCL read data from .csv file package

Tags: csv, tcl, package

I am new on TCL and I would like to create code to parse data from an external .csv file. I have already install tcllib 1.17 and when I run the script I have the following problem with the packages.

Can't find package struct::matrix
while executing
"package require struct::matrix" ... Same for csv

My Code is

```
package require Tcl 8.4
package require struct::matrix
package require csv

# Read it in
set m [struct::matrix]
set f [open "document.csv" r]
csv::read2matrix $f $m
close $f

# Now use the matrix ops to work with it.
#set titles [$m get row 0]
#set domains [$m get column 0]

#Display table
puts "Display tables:"
loop y 0 [$m rows] {
loop x 0 [$m columns] {
    puts -nonewline [format "%4d" [$m get cell $x $y]]
}
puts ""
}
```

Do you have any ideas on fixing this problem?

Comment: I don't remember how I exactly did it on a friend's PC, but can you try to do [`tcl::tm::path add`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/tm.htm#M5) followed by the path to the csv and the struct::matrix packages? To confirm the path, try to go to the tcl folder, then `.../lib/teapot/package/tcl/teapot/tcl8/8.4` for csv and `.../lib/teapot/package/tcl/teapot/tcl8/8.2/struct` for struct::matrix.

Comment: Hello again! I am using tcllib-1.17 and I add the path of  the required packages package
"require struct::matrix 2.0 [list source [file join $/usr/lib/tcllib1.17/struct matrix.tcl]]"
and I face the same problem. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: So you did not use `tcl::tm::path add`?

Comment: Thank you Jerry for your quick reply. Is it possible to give me an example of how I can use this command and where excactly?

Comment: 8.4 is really old. If it's possible please use a more recent version. 8.5 at least. There are some new features introduced in 8.5 that can't be backported to 8.4 and lots of new code use them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

```
lappend auto_path "/path/to/tcllib1.17"
package require struct::matrix
```

Comment: please provide more details about were to include this lines and why does it solve it